# Reporting framework for Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, reporting

All,
Is there a proven working reporting framework for GAE that
1) It's lightweight
2) It can aggregate data from Cloud SQL (JPA)
3) It's java base

Amir

Comment: what types of output format do you need?

Comment: PDF? CSV? XML? Any format would work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unusual to need reporting but not have specific output format requirements.  If you are looking to dump XML or CSV, then you should simply write your cloud query, extract the ResultSet data and return the data in the format you need - just custom code.  If you want to produce reports in PDF for example, I would use iText or Docmosis to create the documents.  With iText your code would extact the ResultSet and build the PDF document.  With Docmosis you would work the same way, or pass the ResultSet to Docmosis to extract on your behalf, but your template would create your format.

Either way, the JPA / Cloud SQL is part of your application code.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

I hope that helps.